# pipe between 2 child process do not produce any output

Tags: c, shell, pipe

So far, i got a function execute_command(command_t) that can execute simple command such as "ls -l", "cat test.txt", etc. However, when I try to implement pipe, it doesn't produce anything. here's the code:

```
int thePipe[2];
pid_t child = fork();
int status1=0;
pipe(thePipe);
if(child==(pid_t)-1){
    fprintf(stderr, "error when fork the process\n");
} else if(child==0){
    close one pipe and make duplicate
    execute command[0]
} else{
    waitpid(child, &status1, 0);
}
int status2=0;
pid_t child2 = fork();
pipe(thePipe);
if(child2==(pid_t)-1){
    fprintf(stderr, "error when fork the process\n");
} else if(child2==0){
    close one pipe and make duplicate
    execute command[1];
} else {
    waitpid(child2, &status2, 0);
}
```

if the input command is:

```
cat test.txt | grep aaa
```

the command "cat test.txt" will be stored in "c->u.command[0]" and command "grep aaa" will be stored in "c->u.command[1]".

did I do something wrong? thanks

Comment: It's because you fork before the use of the pipe function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create *one* pipe between your two children.  That is, call `pipe()` *once* and then have both children use it.  You're calling it twice, overwriting the original pipe with a new one.  Basically, keeping your layout/order of things, you want:

```
create pipe
fork()
if child {
    close read end of pipe
    send stdout to write end of pipe
    exec command[0]
}
fork()
if child {
    close write end of pipe
    set stdin to read end of pipe
    exec command[1]
}
close read and write ends of pipe
wait for children to finish
```